# Security Concern with Restoring In App Purchases

Tags: android, ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

So, I have an app that has just been rejected by Apple because of not implementing a restorePurchases button for the user to restore any non-consumable items that they have bought.

I understand the logic behind that, and feel bad for missing it (or not understanding the blocking aspect of its implementation, at least), but I have an unusual case (which I'm not sure is all that unusual, but can't find a lot of best practices around it...)

My app is cross platform, and so the user can purchase the same item on Android as well as iOS, and those purchases need to persist across platforms... so, upon successful authentication, I update a value in my backend that both clients have read-write access to.

Because of this, I consider that I persist purchases across devices and platforms just fine... but the purchases are tied to an account on my applications User class.

Now, if I am to implement the button as required by Apple, what is stopping a User from restoring a purchase *associated with an Apple ID* to another User in my application database... potentially causing a 'revenue leak' so to speak - for example, signing in as a Friends User, restoring the purchase, which in my case would copy the purchase over to the User class... then I have two Users with only one piece of associated revenue...

So... Questions:

1) Am I being naive about the ability to cheat the system? 
2) Does anyone have any best practices about how to solve / workaround this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple addresses this in the [In-App Purchase Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/RequestPayment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH4-SW6)

Firstly, you can provide your user's account name with the purchase information to assist Apple to detect irregular activity -

> **Detecting Irregular Activity**
>
> The App Store uses an irregular activity detection engine to help
>   combat fraud. Some apps can provide additional information to improve
>   the engine’s ability to detect unusual transactions. If your users
>   have an account with you, in addition to their App Store accounts,
>   provide this additional piece of information when requesting payment.

Then, when it comes to restoring purchases you can provide this same user account information to `restoreCompletedTransactionsWithApplicationUsername:` method -

> **Restoring Completed Transactions**
>
> Your app starts the process by calling the
>   restoreCompletedTransactions method of SKPaymentQueue. This sends a
>   request to the App Store to restore all of your app’s completed
>   transactions. If your app sets a value for the applicationUsername
>   property of its payment requests, as described in Detecting Irregular
>   Activity, use the restoreCompletedTransactionsWithApplicationUsername:
>   method to provide the same information when restoring transactions.

Finally, you can use the receipt information on your server to correlate the original transaction with the restored transaction for the same userid and not restore the functionality if it doesn't match.

Comment: Aha, never caught the part about the Username... thanks! How do I provide it with the payment ?

Comment: Which payment are you referring to?

Comment: "If your users have an account with you, in addition to their App Store accounts, provide this additional piece of information when requesting payment." ... any idea how to include my Username with the payment ?

Comment: Yes, you specify it on the `applicationUsername` property of the `SKPaymentRequest`.

Comment: There is some sample code at the link in my answer that shows how to hash the username before sending it to Apple

Comment: i saw that... but it doenst show about un-hashing it .. or does Apple take care of that on the server side ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66615/discussion-between-jesses-co-tt-and-paulw11).

Comment: You don't need to unhash it. Apple just stores it as an opaque value that is compared.